# Matlab serial port changing baudrate in runtime

Tags: matlab, serial-port

i'm trying to handle a program which must change baudrate while in execution

i tried :

```
s=serial('COM1');

set(s,'BaudRate',300);

fopen(s);

% receive data

set(s,'BaudRate',9600);

%receive data

fclose(s)
```

but it didnt work.Then i tried :

```
s=serial('COM1');

set(s,'BaudRate',300);

s1=serial('COM1');

set(s1,'BaudRate',9600);


fopen(s);

%receive data with 300 rate

tic;

fclose(s);

fopen(s1);

toc;

%receive data with 9600 rate

fclose(s1);
```

it did work but there is some missing data because of that toc is 1.09 second.

how can i fix it without missing data

thanks.

Comment: What didn't work in your first solution ? I do not get an error when I change the baud rate with the serial port open.

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Read, change baud rate, then read is a rare scenario because each end of the serial link would have to coordinate the baud rate change.  If the baud rate change was not properly synchronized, then the receivers at each end are likely to lose data.

Comment: in first solution serial port stops receiving data when baudrate changes     (i dont know the reason)